# object keys are undefined in if conditional, but inside the if statement I can access it

Tags: json, node.js, if-statement, electron

As the title states, I have a variable which is a javascript object, i'm comparing it with another js object by stringifying them. The problem is that the variable is completely accessible without calling the keys, so these
`if(JSON.stringify(response) == JSON.stringify(lastcmd))` 
`if(JSON.stringify(response.id) == JSON.stringify(lastcmd))`
work perfectly fine, but accessing lastcmd's id key will cause it to throw undefined.
`if(JSON.stringify(response) == JSON.stringify(lastcmd.id))`

full code link [here](https://pastebin.com/eHgv3giw)

Edit: Here's the JSON

```
{ "id" : "001", "app": "msgbox", "contents": { "title": "Newpaste", "message": "I'm a edited paste!" } }
```

Edit2: Here's the code on the post

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, dialog, ClientRequest } = require("electron");
const axios = require("axios");
const url = require("url");

let win = null;
let lastcmd;

function grabCurrentInstructions(fetchurl) {
  return axios
    .get(fetchurl)
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      //console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function boot() {
  //console.log(process.type);
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    resizable: true,
    show: false,
    frame: false
  });
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  //Loop everything in here every 10 seconds

  var requestLoop = setInterval(getLoop, 4000);
  function getLoop() {
    grabCurrentInstructions("https://pastebin.com/raw/i9cYsAt1").then(
      response => {
        //console.log(typeof lastcmd);
        //console.log(typeof response);
        if (JSON.stringify(response.app) == JSON.stringify(lastcmd.app)) {
          console.log(lastcmd.app);
          clearInterval(requestLoop);
          requestLoop = setInterval(getLoop, 4000);
        } else {
          lastcmd = response;
          switch (response.app) {
            case "msgbox":
              dialog.showMessageBox(response.contents);
              //console.log(lastcmd);
              clearInterval(requestLoop);
              requestLoop = setInterval(getLoop, 1000);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
app.on("ready", boot);
```

And here's the error:

```
(node:7036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at grabCurrentInstructions.then.response (C:\Users\The Meme Machine\Desktop\nodejsprojects\electronrat\index.js:42:64)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: I see some contradiction in your question and the sample code you linked. In your sample code, you seem to be comparing response.app with lastcmd.app. Are you sure there is an id key? Did you meant to access response.app.id, by any chance?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to add my json to the post, but no I have the ID key in the root object.
Added the error and all the code to the post.

Comment: I can not see `*.id` in your code you have provided.

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: The error message says it all, `lastcmd` is `undefined` when you want to access `lastcmd.id`. You only define `lastcmd` *after* you want to access its `id` property.

Comment: Aha, that did the trick, as I would need to ignore all past commands while running, I can skip the last given instruction and copy that value to lastcmd as I don't want to execute it, I'll post the fix in a second. Thank you so much, I wouldnt've seen the error myself!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user [str](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906113/str) I saw that my lastcmd was undefined when I ran the comparison the first time, this would break it and thereby loop the same error over and over, by addding

```
grabCurrentInstructions("https://pastebin.com/raw/i9cYsAt1").then(
    response => {
      lastcmd = response;
    }
  );
```

below this line

```
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
```

I made sure that the last command sent while the app was offline wouldn't be executed on launch **and** fixing my problem at the same time!